# Clear an MUI Select value using react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, react-hook-form

I have a dropdown where a user can choose from "Item 1", "Item 2" and "Item 3". There is also a "Reset" button that lets the user clear their choice to make a new one.

Here's my code :

```
import React from "react";
import { Button, FormControl, MenuItem, Select } from "@mui/material";
import { Controller, useForm, FormProvider } from "react-hook-form";

export default function App() {
  const methods = useForm();
  const { control, resetField } = methods;
  const dropDownItems = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"];

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form>
        <FormControl sx={{ width: "51%" }}>
          <Controller
            name="firstItem"
            control={control}
            rules={{ required: true }}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <Select {...field} id="firstItem">
                {dropDownItems.map((name) => (
                  <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
                    {name}
                  </MenuItem>
                ))}
              </Select>
            )}
          />
        </FormControl>
      </form>
      <Button onClick={() => resetField("firstItem")}>Reset</Button>
    </FormProvider>
  );
}
```

I expect the `resetField` to empty the choice of the dropdown on clicking the reset button. And it does so, but only in the state of the form (and the display does *not* change). I'm assuming there is something about `control` that I do not quite understand, but an afternoon of looking around did not let me find the answer.

I also tried using `setValue` instead of `resetField`, to no avail.

Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/blue-platform-74tgg8?file=/src/App.js

What am I missing? Thanks for the help :)

Edit: In my use-case, this is part of a bigger form, so using `reset` to reset the fields entirely does not work for me.

Comment: `useForm({ defaultValues: { firstItem: '' }});`
It you do not provide the default/initial value the input keeps switching from controlled to uncontrolled input. Reset has to know what value to reset to :).

Comment: Exactly. Thanks man. I had just found this by asking ChatGPT and it basically gave the same answer. You may provide this as an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Resolving MUI Select Value Clearing Issue with React Hook Form**

common issue faced by developers working with React and Material-UI (MUI) Select components, particularly when integrating them with React Hook Form. The problem at hand involves the clearing of values in a dependent dropdown scenario, specifically when one dropdown's selection should reset the value of another dropdown and display it as empty in the UI.

Don't forget to set the default values in the useForm hook of the fields which you are going to reset.

```
 const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    control,
    trigger,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors },
    resetField,
  } = useForm({ defaultValues: { installmentDay: "" } }); 
const frequency = watch("frequency");
const [installmentDay, setInstallmentDay] = useState(watch("installmentDay"));
  <Select
    name="Frequency"
    required
    value={frequency}
    {...register("frequency", {
      required: "required.",
    })}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setInstallmentDay("");
      resetField("installmentDay");
      //setValue("installmentDay", "");
      setValue("frequency", e.target.value);
      trigger("frequency");
    }}
    defaultValue={""}
  >
    {getfrequency.map((val, index) => {
      return (
        <MenuItem
          value={val.code}
          key={val.code}
        >
          {val.value}
        </MenuItem>
      );
    })}
  </Select>

  <Select
    name="installmentDay"
    required
    value={installmentDay}
    disabled={frequency ? false : true}
    {...register("installmentDay", {
      // required: true,
      required: "required",
    })}
    onChange={(e) => {
      setValue("installmentDay", e.target.value);
      trigger("installmentDay");
      setInstallmentDay(e.target.value);
    }}
  >
    {validator?.sys_dates.trim().split("").length <= 0
      ? getInstallmentDay()?.map((day, index) => {
          return <MenuItem value={index + 1}>{day}</MenuItem>;
        })
      : validator?.sys_dates?.split("/").map((day, index) => {
          return <MenuItem value={day}>{day}</MenuItem>;
        })}
  </Select>
```